# Launch SSH access from a remote Server error, possible caused by ssh key forwarding

Tags: ssh, remote

There is a VM ubuntu server I am using which is named `vm`.

I used to remotely log into it through SSH public key.

But now I need to use ssh to other servers **FROM** `vm`, ex. pushing to heroku.

There is an unexpected results for that:

1. When use my local console to remote control `vm`,  use `ssh` push won't succeed, it complains about failed publickey.
2. However, when I use the `vm` directly (from the linux terminal), I could push with `ssh` without error.

My first thought would be some mis-configuration of the ssh key forwarding, any clues for me to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried the "-a" option for `ssh` from your local console, to completely disable forwarding agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to forward your SSH key when you connect to the machine VM :

```
ssh -A user@VM
```

Comment: Why should I enable key forwarding?

Comment: If you have the ssh key on your machine you have to use the forwarding. If there  is only a password authentification on heroku thé you have to disable the forwarding with the option -a. And If you need a ssh key on VM you have to use the option -i /path/to/your.key.